# After resetting my Binatone router i lost my wifi connectivity

Tags: router, wireless-router

When i connect to the router wifi connection it displays other wifi connection options like PEAP,TLS,TTLS,PWD and so on.

Is there any way in making successful connection to the router through LAN or wifi?
Please i need a help to fix it

Router name: Binatone

Model: DT845W

Comment: Thats possible, you need to re-configure the router. If it has been used as a repeater before, you need to re-add the network and password it repeats, if it has been spreading internet that it receives from an ethernet cable, than you need to reconfigure it by running the setup if there is one. Sometimes this can only be done by the provider. You need to check the login address(example 192.168.1.1 or tplinklogin.net), username and password on the back of the router and try to access it.

An example is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEQ9vFxYB9o

Comment: I don't meant to offend you, sometimes internation communication is hard, I did not understand your last comment.

Comment: Router ip will be accessible only if i connect to the router through wifi or LAN. My main issue is iam unable to make connection to my router so i need to fix this and make it work as there is no default wifi connection option as mentioned in question

Comment: contact your ISP and ask them to release your MAC address..most of them block new or suspicious mac address resets for security purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact your ISP and ask for help. If you're lucky enough to have been provided the with the router by your ISP, then your ISP may have an automatic telephone answering program that will guide you step-by-step through the steps required to reset that router to back to its default settings.

Otherwise one of your other options is to call your ISP and ask for help. If you have reset a new [MAC address](https://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-MAC-Address-of-Your-Computer) don't forget to mention that. As a last resort you can buy a new router. Not all routers are compatible with all ISPs, so you should ask your ISP for a hardware recommendation about which routers are compatible before getting a new router.